# Borel $\sigma$-algebra of metric subspace

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I am supposed to show that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. the algebra generated by open sets under complementation and arbitrary unions) of a metrix subspace $Y$ of metric space $X$ is the same as the intersection of the original algebra with the subspace, i.e. $B_Y=\{A\cap Y:A\in B_X\}$. I am having some trouble with this and would appreciate some pointers, if not outright answers.

The right-to-left direction seemingly works by considering the inclusion map $\iota:Y\to X$, which is continuous (I think) and therefore measureable. Therefore, it takes elements of the original algebra $A\in B_X$ to elements of the subspace algebra $i^{-1}A\in B_Y$, but $i^{-1}A=A\cap Y$, therefore the RHS is a subset of $B_Y$. For the left-to-right direction I believe I would have to show that every open set in $Y$ is of the form $A\cap Y$, where $A$ is an open set in $X$ and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \tau_X)$ a topological space and $Y \subseteq X$, the classical topology given to $Y$ is called the subspace topology $\tau_Y = \{Y \cap U | U \in \tau_X \}$. Now let's show that the induced metric on $Y$ is the same as the one induced by $X$. The topology induced by the metric of $X$ on $Y$ is generated by the basis of balls $B(y, r)$ with $y \in Y$ end $r \in \mathbb{R}$. If the ball lies in $Y$ then obviously $B(y, r) \cap Y = B(y, r)$. If $B(y, r)$ lies not entirely in $Y$ then obviously you have to take the intersection of the ball with $Y$ so again clearly both topologies are equivalent.

Comment: Is there any way of showing this without invoking the definition of the subspace topology? I believe the intended solution follows a slightly different path (it is recommended to use the fact that the composition of measurable functions is measurable, but I can't seem to find a second function of note besides the inclusion map).

Comment: I mean, you have to give a definition for the topology you are using can yoiu precise the topology you want to use on $Y$ ?

Comment: It's not specified per se, just that $Y$ is a metric subspace of $X$...

Comment: Yes but as such it inherits the topology on $X$, to study open sets on $Y$ you have to decide which topology you study. When nothing is specified you use the "standard" subspace topology.